# Securely redirect to page not in intranet?

Tags: asp.net, security, http, redirect

In an application we are writing we need to have a page that is essentially public but should only be available to certain people.. yep i know very paradoxical!

Its basically a "Submit a support ticket" style page that is hosted outside of a customers intranet but should only be available to users on that intranet.

Naturally making the user sign up for an account is the usual course of action but in this case it isn't really an option..

Is there any way of doing a "secure redirect" to that page?

My initial though would be to use an internal page which redirects appending a unique one time hash to the url which expires and then although its not 100% airtight it is only valid for about 1 min..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways come to mind.

1) Deploy IP restrictions on the web server for the off-network resource. If the request is coming from one of the exit points from your network (proxy server, other public-facing egress points, etc) then allow the connection, otherwise do not.

2) Deploy mutually authenticated SSL on both the web server and a reverse-proxy server on your internal network. Clients connect to the internal reverse-proxy and that proxies them back to the external resource over an SSL connection that is mutually authenticated (so the external web server will only connect over SSL and it will only connect to a client (the reverse-proxy in this case) that has a recognized/accepted client certificate).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.. in the end to fully meet the requirement a small portion of the site needed to be hosted on their server, and as their firewall is so locked down the data is serialzed as JSON and emailed to us! sigh.. corperates hey?!

Answer (score 1):

"Secure Redirect" is meaningless. What you want to do is make sure your ticket submit system will only accept clients connecting from your users' network. This would be a web site configuration thing.

Comment: Hi correct me if im wrong but isnt that only possible on intranet sites?

Comment: Why would you think that? Presumably the public side of their network can be identified, too.

Comment: Okay, my bad i must be mistaken.. Can you post an example a link to some docs, anything like that please?

Comment: @DanielUpton One possibility would be to verify that the client IP is one of their public IPs, if possible.